# pandas groupby column and check if group meets multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame that looks like the following:

```
      X       Y      Date       are_equal
0   50.0    10.0  2018-08-19      False
1    NaN    10.0  2018-08-19      False
2    NaN    50.0  2018-08-19       True
3   10.0     NaN  2018-08-21      False
4    1.0     NaN  2018-08-19      False
5    NaN    10.0  2018-08-22      False
6   10.0     NaN  2018-08-21      False
```

The `are_equal` column indicates that a value in `Y` is in `X` for the same date (in this case `50.0`).

I am trying to group by date and find whether `X` contains a specific value (say `1.0`) for a date that contains `are_equal` `True`.

My approach was to use `df.iterrows()` and get the row at next index after meeting the condition `df['are_equal'] == True`. However, the rows aren't necessarily ordered.

How can I group by `Date` and check if a date contains `True` in `are_equal` and `1.0` in column `X` for that same date?

The output I'm trying to achieve is a new Boolean column that looks like this:

```
   contains_specific_value
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    True
5    False
6    False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do `apply`, this can add more condition but slow. You can check the other solution from `transform`

```
df['New']=df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x : (x['X']==1)&x['are_equal'].any()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df
Out[101]: 
      X     Y        Date  are_equal    New
0  50.0  10.0  2018-08-19      False  False
1   NaN  10.0  2018-08-19      False  False
2   NaN  50.0  2018-08-19       True  False
3  10.0   NaN  2018-08-21      False  False
4   1.0   NaN  2018-08-19      False   True
5   NaN  10.0  2018-08-22      False  False
6  10.0   NaN  2018-08-21      False  False
```

Or `transform`

```
df['X'].eq(1)&(df.groupby('Date').X.transform('any'))
Out[102]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: X, dtype: bool
```